# Are there airport identifiers assigned to heliports?

Tags: faa, location-identifiers

FAA databases list multiple Official Facility Names with a given Associated City Name, for example:

> CITY: Fort Lauderdale
>   FACILITY NAMES: Fort Lauderdale/Hollywood International (FLL); BSO Public Safety Helistop; Port Everglades; Broward Health Medical Center; Fort Lauderdale Executive (FXE).

Only **FLL** and **FXE** are airports. The rest are heliports. Are there airport identifiers assigned to heliports?

Comment: Okay, so what are you asking?

Comment: There is no naming convention to distinguish them.

Comment: "Class B, C, D, E, G airports" - there's no such thing. Airports do not have classes, airspace does.

Comment: I edited your question to what I understand it to be. If I'm off track please edit it to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Heliports are airports so they get assigned identifiers just as a fixed wing airport does

Answer (score 3):

Generally, not all airports have an ICAO or IATA code. Helipads and small airports usually don't rank a code from either of them. IATA won't have any reason to assign a code unless there is some kind of passenger service out of them. ICAO won't have any reason unless there is some significant international service from there. There is more info on the criteria for ICAO codes on [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14585/8730). Those helipads have FAA identifiers, though.

- BSO Public Safety Helistop: [FA10](https://www.airnav.com/airport/FA10)
- Port Everglades: [2FD4](https://www.airnav.com/airport/2FD4)
- Broward Health Medical Center: [6FD8](https://www.airnav.com/airport/6FD8)

FAA-only ID's have either three or four digits and always contain at least one number.

From the FAA's [JO 7350.9K - Location Identifiers](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/7350.9) (p.1-2-3):

> Two−letter, two−number identifiers are assigned to private−use landing facilities in the United
>   States and its jurisdictions which do not meet the
>   requirements for three−character assignments. They
>   are keyed by the two−letter Post Office or
>   supplemental abbreviation (listed below) of the state
>   with which they are associated. The two−letter code
>   appears in the first two, middle, or last two positions
>   of the four−character code.

There are helipads that have IATA and ICOA codes, though. For example, [West 30th Street Heliport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_30th_Street_Heliport) (IATA: JRA, ICAO: KJRA, FAA: JRA) in New York.

Comment: *"ICAO won't have any reason unless there is some significant international service from there."* That might perhaps be the case in the USA, but I don't think it's the case globally. Wikipedia makes the (seemingly uncited) claim that *"In small countries like Belgium or the Netherlands, almost all aerodromes have an ICAO code. For bigger countries like the UK or Germany this is not feasible,"* which seems plausible; certainly my local (Sweden) airport has an ICAO code, but insofar as I know zero non-GA or heavy traffic on the 1300 m runway.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm sort of generalizing. I don't know the specific criteria for either ICAO or IATA to assign an ID. When I get a chance I'll do some poking around and see if I can find some specifics

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Added a link to a related (possibly duplicate) question about ICAO's criteria