# Which official document lists active airport identifiers?

Tags: flight-training, usa, chart-supplement

Is there an official FAA document with which I can find an airport by its identifier code if I do not have a name or location? In the Chart Supplement I can find the airport if I know the city and state. However, I can’t seem to find any sort of reverse lookup document that lets me find it by code only.

I know I can search on SkyVector/ForeFlight/etc. but I am specifically asking if there is a government published “index document” for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [FAA JO 7350.9L - Location Identifiers](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/7350.9) contains complete lists under decode subsections organized alphabetically. Example:

[image]

Comment: Lol I looked for this for a while by very specific googling and didn’t find it. How’d you find that?

Comment: @Pugz: Sorry I don't recall, as I found it 3 months ago and added it to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/47482). So I simply looked for that answer :D

Comment: @Pugz - You can search the [FAA documents](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/) for "location identifiers" and that document page will be a result.

Answer (score 1):

**Digital Aeronautical Flight Information File**

This database, commonly just called "DAFIF", is maintained by the National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency (NGA). Unfortunately, updates to this database are no longer published to public domain as of 2006. If you are not an authorized user, you can still use pre-2006 data from sources around the internet, which will likely be good enough for what you need. Look around for "DAFIF cycle 0610". The database contains ARPT.TXT, a tab-separated text file with metadata for both large and small airports around the world, including various types of identifiers (ICAO, FAA-ID, Name, Lat/Lon, etc).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAFIF