# How is a Class E airport distinguished from a Class G airport, based on the identifier?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa

Some small uncontrolled airports have "K" identifiers such as KPHK (Palm Beach County Glades) "Pahokee". Others such as 42M (Thayer Mem) "Thayer" have a numeric identifier. Both have 122.9 CTAF listed. Pahokee is Class G, Thayer is E.

My question is how is an "E" airport distinguished from a "G" airport on the basis of the identifier?

Comment: Are you referring to the US?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14583/62)

Answer (score 5):

Airport identifiers do not distinguish the airspace that surrounds them. As for [why airports start with a K you can look at the answer here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16205/where-did-the-k-identifier-prefix-for-us-airports-come-from). To figure out the airspace that an airport sits in you must look at the airspace designation lines around it ([see page 10 here](https://ticc.tamu.edu/Documents/OtherInfo/VFR_Symbols.pdf)).

Comment: Your link to "history" appears to have been changed. It now has just a list of airport codes. I was looking for an explanation of why some US airports have three letters and numbers, and no K at all.

Answer (score 0):

The AFD / Chart Supplement gives further information, especially airports that have different airspace classes at different times.  For example, KMCE has that dashed magenta circle around it on the sectional, and in the chart supplement says "AIRSPACE: CLASS E svc 1600–0100Z‡; other times CLASS G."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/41982)

Comment: I disagree.  Perhaps not the greatest or most complete answer ever to appear on this website, but much, much better than some.  And your comment regarding reputation just comes across as snippy.  Let the community decide this.

Comment: @MichaelHall It might be worth noting that the above comment with Pondlife's name on it was automatically generated; Pondlife did not write that.

Comment: @Pondlife is correct, this is not an answer, but it's good information and entirely appropriate as a comment.  And a real human actually wrote this.

Comment: @Tanner Swett, how is a person to know which comments to ascribe to the individual named, and which ones are to be disregarded as the product of runaway AI?  And PJNoes, I won't debate opinion with you.  I didn't say it was a good answer.

Comment: Just wondering how many of the people (or bots) who don't like my comment as an answer actually read the AF/D / Chart Supplement.  It literally tells you, for every airport, what class of airspace it's in, and whether it changes when the tower is closed.
Aymhan's original answer stated that the airport code, whether IATA, FAA 3-letter, or alphanumeric does not indicate class of airspace, so that part of the answer was already provided.  The way you tell is by airspace boundary markings on the sectional (answer also already provided), and/or by looking up the airport in the AFD / Chart supp.